# Question about adding javascript:OpenPopUpPage to my SharePoint sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, javascript, hyperlink

I have the following problems with showing javascript pop up page

- I have added a content editor web part inside my team site, then I insert an embedded code snippet with the following code:- `<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/sites/Intranet/SitePages/AboutIntranet.aspx');">About this</a>` 
  My idea was to open a popup window showing the associated site page. But this did not work, and an empty dialog box was show. While if I write the following snippet to refer to bing.com it will work well :- `<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('www.bing.com');">About this</a>`

So any idea about this ?

- Second problem, When the popup windows was shown for `bing.com` users will not be able to expand the java script pop up window  , they can only use the tool bar to view the window details. So any idea how to make the java script pop up expandable?
- Third problem. Is there a way to add a pop-up to a quick lunch links? Because if I write `<a href= …..>` Inside the web URL for a quick lunch link, I will get an error mentioning that the URL must start with http?
  Thanks a lot for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

John,

The OpenPopUpPage() method takes multiple arguments and from what I have found scrubbing the internet, you must include the callback method when using it so that you do not get a blank dialog (even if it means just passing null). Try the following:

`OpenPopUpPage('/sites/Intranet/SitePages/AboutIntranet.aspx', RefreshPage);`

Reference [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410825(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would get you what you want:

```
function OpenDialog(strPageURL) 
{
    var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    dialogOptions.url = strPageURL;
    dialogOptions.title = 'Welcome to SharePoint';
    dialogOptions.allowMaximize= true;
    dialogOptions.width = 750;
    dialogOptions.height = 500;
    /* CloseCallback will get called when the Dialog is closed */
    dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);  
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); // Open the Dialog
    return false;
}
```

Source: http://sharethepunto.blogspot.de/2014/06/how-to-create-pop-up-dialog.html

I haven't had the problem where you get an empty Dialog box with `OpenPopUpPage();`

Answer (score -1):

Take the reference of this site.

http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodal.htm

Comment: the link does not answer my questions, can you advice please ?

Comment: Could you try once with full absolute url of your site.